# Is it considered eosinophilia if the total eosinophil count is normal but the eosinophil percentage is high?

Tags: immune-system, blood-tests, inflammation, cbc-complete-blood-count

If the total eosinophil count is normal but the eosinophil percentage is high, is it considered eosinophilia, or is it merely grounds for a rerun of the test?

In a paper by [Kovalski and Weller (2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5293177/), I read that:

> Hence, eosinophilia is often recognized based on an elevation of eosinophils in the blood. Absolute eosinophil counts exceeding 450 to 550 cells/µL, depending on laboratory standards, are reported as elevated. Percentages generally above 5% of the differential are regarded as elevated in most institutions, **although the absolute count should be calculated before a determination of eosinophilia is made**. This is done by multiplying the total white cell count by the percentage of eosinophils.

It confuses me a bit. What is the main criterion defining eosinophilia - the percentage or the absolute count? Or is it either?

I tried googling but there seems to be no simple explanation.